# Multiple window.open pages

Tags: javascript, checkbox, redirect

I have a javascript function that is like this assigned to an input submit

```
function choose () {
if(document.getElementById("first").checked) {
    window.open("http://www.facebook.com", '_blank');
}
if(document.getElementById("second").checked) {
    window.open("http://www.twitter.com", '_blank');    
}
if(document.getElementById("third").checked) {
    window.open("http://www.linkedin.com", '_blank');   
} }
```

In fact I want the browser to open ONE new window if the first checkbox is checked, or to open TWO new windows if both first and second are checked, etc..

But if I check both first and second checkboxes the browser only open the first link. What's the problem?

Comment: change checkboxes to buttons - one window to user click

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in the **popup blocker** by your browser.

1. Popup blockers prevent opening multiple windows. Imagine the mess one could make if this was possible!
2. Popups are usualy blocked when opened on page load, but they are not blocked when they are triggered by the user in a later event.

There is really not much you can do about this. **But** you can change the behaviour of the site. For example: You could create one popup that contains a tabber (jQuery UI) which contains `iframes` containing each site. This is a good workaround.

You can also use a CSS based popup (such as Lightbox). This is not a real browser window, but a div that is centered instead. Also possible using jQuery UI.

Comment: Thank you @bytecode77. "You could create one popup that contains a tabber (jQuery UI) which contains iframes containing each site. This is a good workaround." Can you give me a little example of coding it? I don't exactly know how to do it. Thank you very much

Comment: It's very easy: jQueryUI - https://jqueryui.com/tabs/ has a tabber control which you can use. The iframe shouldn't be a problem, too.